# Arch Linux - щелчки в наушниках

Tags: linux, аудио, archlinux

Перед и после воспроизведения видео слышу щелчок в наушниках. Это связано с экономией электроэнергии, однако не могу понять, как это выключить.

Comment: Какой звуковой сервер вы используете — PulseAudio, PipeWire, никакой?

Comment: Я использую PipeWire

Comment: Я решил проблему: нужно было создать файл powersave.conf в /etc/modprobe.d/ и добавить туда строку: options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N

Comment: А чтобы проверить, включен ли энергосберегающий режим, можно ввести эту команду в cmd: cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save Если 1 то включен, 0 выключен.